# Add data validation and Formulas in one cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying in google sheets to add a data validation where users can select ( Today, Incomplete) then if selected "Today" the cell will display today's date, and if "incomplete" then just display it as it is.

I did the formula

`if(E2:2="Today",(TODAY()),"Incomplete")`

But then add validation removes the formula if selected Today. Can someone help me, please.

Comment: Sorry it’s Google sheets.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, showing the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a tab called 'DVs'
in A2 of that tab write "Incomplete".
in A3 of that tab, *manually* put today's date.

then point your Data Validation at those two cells.

then Tools>Script Editor.

then erase the code that is there that looks like this:

```
function myFunction(){

}
```

then paste this code.

```
function setToday(){
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('DVs').getRange('A3').setValue(date);
}
```

then Save.

Then click on the little alarm clock at the left to open the triggers.
Then at the bottom right, click on the button to add a trigger.

then choose the function, and set a "time driven" trigger that runs every day after midnight.

Then Save.

That should do it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Can you please if possible share a google sheet. I have tested it but the date stays as the one I entered manually

Comment: If you share a google sheet, I would be happy to demonstrate how to do it

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cMm3tBeZQbnLPGcWeKLbVQDM6QlCzm4aGOyNPx5mVzc/edit?usp=sharing here please

Comment: you'll need to use Spreadsheet settings to get the timezone correct for when that script should happen.  Your trigger needs to be set up in the same time zone as where your client will use it.

Comment: @AlmoDev I saw some points awarded here.  Did this work for you?